# Splitting tkinter canvas and frame apart

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Got a tkinter frame on the left being used for labels, checkbuttons, etc.  On the right is a canvas displaying a map.  I can scroll over the map and it will give the longitude/latitude coordinates of where the mouse pointer is located on the map at the time in question.  I can click on the map and it will zoom in on the map.  The problem is when I'm on the frame where I want to display underlying map data as I scroll the mouse across the frame the longitude/latitude changes, even though I'm not on the canvas.  If I click on the frame, haven't put any checkbuttons on there yet to test it that way, it zooms right in just like it would over on the canvas.

Is there any way to split apart the action 'sensing' of the frame and canvas to keep them separate.

I would post up the code, a bit lengthy, but I got get out of here as I'm already running late.

Edit:

I'm back and thanks to Bryan's reply I think I understand what he was saying to do, just not sure how to do it.  In a couple of attempts nothing seemed to work.  Granted I'm still not fully sure of the (self,parent) 'addressing' method in the code below.

Also I see high probability coming up in the not to distant future of needing to be able to reference the mouse button to both t he canvas and the frame separately, aka have it do different things depending on where I have clicked on.  Fortunately with the delay thanks to having to get out of here earlier and with Bryan's answer I have been able to shorten the code down even more and now have code that is doing exactly what I'm talking about.  The delay in posting code worked to my benefit.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self,bg='black', width=1366, height=714)
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self,bg='gray', width=652, height=714)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background="black", width=714, height=714)
        self.canvas.pack_propagate(0)
        self.canvas.place(x=652,y=0)
        self.frame1.pack_propagate(0)
        self.frame1.place(x=0,y=0)

        self.longitudecenter = -95.9477127
        self.latitudecenter = 36.989772
        self.p = 57.935628
        global v
        s = Canvas(self, width=150, height=20)
        s.pack_propagate(0)
        s.place(x=0,y=695)
        v = Label(s, bg='gray',fg='black',borderwidth=0,anchor='w')
        v.pack()

        parent.bind("<Motion>", self.on_motion)
        self.canvas.focus_set()

        self.canvas.configure(xscrollincrement=1, yscrollincrement=1)

   def on_motion(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete("sx")
        self.startx, self.starty = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x),self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        px = -(round((-self.longitudecenter + (self.p/2))- (self.startx * (self.p/714)),5))
        py = round((self.latitudecenter + (self.p/2))-(self.starty * (self.p /714)),5)
        v.config(text = "Longitude: " + str(px))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is part of what I've been using.  How do I change it so I can bind to to the frame and to the canvas separately.  Right now I only need, with the case of the mouse position, to be able to bind to the canvas, but in the future I will need to be able to use mouse clicks, maybe even mouse position separately on the canvas and frame.(who knows given how much this project has changed/advanced since I started it three weeks ago...the sky is the limit).

Comment: just bind the mouse movement to the canvas. It sounds like you've bound it to the entire app. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would guess you need only a dozen or so lines of code to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: I updated the question and included working bad code, unlike unworking bad code I had this morning when I initially posted.  How do bind to separately to both the canvas and the frame?  I feel the need is just around the corner when I'm going to need to bind to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a binding to only fire for a specific widget, but the binding on that widget rather than on a containing widget.

Change this:

```
parent.bind("<Motion>", self.on_motion)
```

To this:

```
self.canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.on_motion)
```

Comment: For knowledge, I can't find where I thought I saw it referenced, is parent taking the binding to frame, in the case of my posted code above?  Do I have this setup correctly so frame is the containing widget with frame1 and self.canvas contained within?

Comment: In your code, `parent` is the root window. Within the class, `self` is the frame that contains the canvas.