# Getting rid of border on tkinter label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In my most recent posting, the code does exactly what I need it do...is there a way to get rid of the border/lighter gray area around the label?  I want to only see the text.

[Splitting tkinter canvas and frame apart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475605/splitting-tkinter-canvas-and-frame-apart)

I have tried changing the label code to

```
v = Label(s, bg='gray',fg='black',borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0,highlightcolor='gray',relief='sunken',anchor='w')
```

This still leaves the side borders that can be plainly seen in the code at the above link. I just inserted relief cause I saw someone else's post using it and thought I would give it a try versus leaving the relief flat as set by default. Made no difference.

How do I get rid of the light gray sides that are appearing on the `Label`.  I know this is about to really become important probably as soon as this evening or tomorrow morning.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Based on the nature of the question, you should only need half a dozen or so lines of code.

Comment: The "border" appears to simply be the extra space in the canvas in which you've placed the label.